# Deploy node js application on heroku and error: Application error An error occurred in the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

When referenced in the browser under `http: // localhost: 8080 /` I can see the inscription `Hello World with Express`. I am trying to deposit the following application on heroku. I followed the tutorial on heroku.

1 )create new app

2) App name

3) region Europe

4) heroku login

5) $ cd my-project/

$ git init

$ heroku git:remote -a app-app

$ git add .

$ git commit -am "make it better"

$ git push heroku master

The application has been built, I am trying to run it I have an error:

> Application error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs
>   for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

**api-routes**

```
    // api-routes.js
    // Initialize express router
    let router = require('express').Router();
    // Set default API response
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.json({
            status: 'API Its Working',
            message: 'Welcome to RESTHub crafted with love!',
        });
    });
    // Import contact controller
    var contactController = require('./contactController');
    // Contact routes
    router.route('/contacts')
        .get(contactController.index)
        .post(contactController.new);

    router.route('/contacts/:contact_id')
        .get(contactController.view)
        .patch(contactController.update)
        .put(contactController.update)
        .delete(contactController.delete);


    // Export API routes
    module.exports = router;
```

**contactController.js**

```
    // Import contact model
    Contact = require('./contactModel');
    // Handle index actions
    exports.index = function (req, res) {
        Contact.get(function (err, contacts) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({
                    status: "error",
                    message: err,
                });
            }
            res.json({
                status: "success",
                message: "Contacts retrieved successfully",
                data: contacts
            });
        });
    };
    // Handle create contact actions
    exports.new = function (req, res) {
        var contact = new Contact();
        contact.name = req.body.name ? req.body.name : contact.name;
        contact.gender = req.body.gender;
        contact.email = req.body.email;
        contact.phone = req.body.phone;
    // save the contact and check for errors
        contact.save(function (err) {
            // Check for validation error
            if (err)
                res.json(err);
            else
                res.json({
                    message: 'New contact created!',
                    data: contact
                });
        });
    };
    // Handle view contact info
    exports.view = function (req, res) {
        Contact.findById(req.params.contact_id, function (err, contact) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({
                message: 'Contact details loading..',
                data: contact
            });
        });
    };
    // Handle update contact info
    exports.update = function (req, res) {
        Contact.findById(req.params.contact_id, function (err, contact) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            contact.name = req.body.name ? req.body.name : contact.name;
            contact.gender = req.body.gender;
            contact.email = req.body.email;
            contact.phone = req.body.phone;
    // save the contact and check for errors
            contact.save(function (err) {
                if (err)
                    res.json(err);
                res.json({
                    message: 'Contact Info updated',
                    data: contact
                });
            });
        });
    };
    // Handle delete contact
    exports.delete = function (req, res) {
        Contact.remove({
            _id: req.params.contact_id
        }, function (err, contact) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({
                status: "success",
                message: 'Contact deleted'
            });
        });
    };

**contactModel.js**

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    // Setup schema
    var contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        gender: String,
        phone: String,
        create_date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    });
    // Export Contact model
    var Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('contact', contactSchema);
    module.exports.get = function (callback, limit) {
        Contact.find(callback).limit(limit);
    }
```

**index.js**

```
    // Import express
    let express = require('express');
    // Import Body parser
    let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    // Import Mongoose
    let mongoose = require('mongoose');
    // Initialize the app
    let app = express();

    // Import routes
    let apiRoutes = require("./api-routes");
    // Configure bodyparser to handle post requests
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // Connect to Mongoose and set connection variable
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://XXXX:XXXX@cluster0-shard-00-00-ov74c.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ov74c.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ov74c.mongodb.net:27017/test123456?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true});


    var db = mongoose.connection;

    // Added check for DB connection

    if(!db)
        console.log("Error connecting db")
    else
        console.log("Db connected successfully")

    // Setup server port
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    // Send message for default URL
    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World with Express'));

    // Use Api routes in the App
    app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
    // Launch app to listen to specified port
    app.listen(port, function () {
        console.log("Running App on port " + port);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
In `package.json` I added `"start": "node index.js"` to `scripts`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```